# Android - I want to fire simple voice or notification every {15 min , 30 min or 1 hour} depends on user's decision

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I am a beginner in android , I want to make a simple app that fires notification or sound every specified time determined by the user.

If the user chooses 1 hour , the app should send the notification every x o,clock
(00:00 , 01:00 , 02:00 ,...... , 11:00)

If he chooses 30 min m the app should send at such times
(00:00 , 00:30 , 01:00 , 01:30)

I want to send this notification, however the application is opened or not
I know that I should use a broadcast receiver, and I know how to send notification ,but the question is how to determine that the time got x o'clock
, x:15 or x:30 to fire the notification

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve such periodic behavior by using Job Scheduler API in android, this article [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-jobscheduler-api-on-android-lollipop--cms-23562) explains it well.

Comment: Thank you , Job Scheduler is the best solution.